# How to remap command based on buffer type?

Tags: key-bindings, plugin-fugitive, plugin-coc

I have coc.vim installed and added suggested mappings, then I installed vim-fugitive and I want to remap the "Toggle an inline diff of the file under the cursor." `fugitive_=` to `Tab` but the coc.vim is using tab for completion.

How I can map the `Tab` to `fugitive_=` only when I enter to vim-fugitive `:GStatus`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `<buffer>` argument to restrict a map to a certain filetype, see `:help :map-local` for details.

Fugitive's status filetype is `fugitive`, so you can try:

```
augroup FugitiveMappings
  autocmd!
  autocmd FileType fugitive nmap <buffer> <Tab> =
augroup
```

You can also call the right function instead of mapping `<Tab>` to `=` (which I think is what you want to do).

If you have a bunch of Fugitive's related customizations you can put all of them in `~/.vim/ftplugin/fugitive.vim` (or `$XDG_COFIG_HOME/nvim/init.vim` if you use Neovim) as @filbranden suggested. You don't need the auto commands if you use this method

Comment: You actually need nmap here to pick up the original = binding (one of those rare cases)

Comment: Good catch! I never remember if I need a recursive or non-recursive map, and try the latter first

Comment: Another good advice is to use an `ftplugin` file such as `~/.vim/ftplugin/fugitive.vim` for the `nmap` command, rather than an `autocmd FileType`...

Comment: @Tae you should maybe put it in a `augroup` (for those who don't know about it). @filbranden I ever wondered if it was better or more reliable to use `ftplugin`. To me, it seems to be a hassle to have more files where I can have only one.

Comment: @Biggybi It's a trade-off... You end up with your configs more fragmented, but on the other hand you don't have to deal with messy autocmd's, augroup's, escaping, managing separate autocmd's for the same matches, etc. These days when your vimrc can (should?) live inside `~/.vim` and it's easy to manage your whole `~/.vim` in git, I think it makes all sense to just use more separate files rather than a single big monolithic config.

Comment: @filbranden `ftplugin`, that's interesting, I will try to look it up. BTW thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @zer09 [`:help ftplugin`](https://vimhelp.org/usr_41.txt.html#ftplugin) is a good start... Also search for ftplugin on this site and you'll find nice pointers on how to use it!